# Having issues altering strings within the array

Tags: java, arrays, string

isValidElement is working fine but I am having an issue with setParts:
If the ip address from the String passed is valid, sets the instance variable parts to store it as 4 integer values.

For example, if ip = "192.000168.0.0000001", parts should become {192,168,0,1}. If the ip address passed is invalid, parts should become {0,0,0,0}

```
public static boolean isValidElement(String token) {
    try{
        int foo = Integer.parseInt("token");
        if(foo >= 0 && foo <= 255)
            return true;
        else 
            return false; 
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex){
        return false;
    }
}

public void setParts(String ip) {
    int i;
    if (isValidElement(ip) == false){
        parts = new int[]{0,0,0,0};
    } else
        if (isValidElement(ip) == true){
            for(i=0; i<parts.length; i++){
                parts[i] = ip;
            }
        }
```

isValidElement is my method checking the string passed is valid or not which works fine and parts[4] being my array.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: what do you expect that `Integer.parseInt("token");` does?

Comment: what do you expect that `parts[i] = ip;` does?

Comment: being not initialized so far, what do you expect that `parts.length` returns?

Comment: (if you don't know the answer to any of those questions, run your code in debug mode, step by step, and observe the values of the variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try splitting your `ip` string on the `.` character, and then attempt to convert each `String` in that array to an `int`. If any of the conversions fail, reset the entire `parts` array:

```
try {
    String[] ipArr = ip.split(Pattern.quote("."));
    for (int i = 0; i < ipArr.length; i++) {
        parts[i] = Integer.parseInt(ipArr[i]);
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    parts = new int[4];
}
```